# Which schema formats allow representation of the directory layout of data? XSD, Protobuf, Thrift... Others?

Tags: java, c++, xml, schema, data-interchange

I am looking to define an object model to file-and-directory-structure mapping, where the files are a mixture of XML and proprietary formats.

I would like to do this in as standard and portable a way as possible, without having to write a lot of boilerplate code to map proprietary formats into the object model. Perhaps these proprietary formats could be defined using ASN.1 .

This directory structure may also contain compressed files, which must be usable as virtual file systems.

I would like to be able to cross-reference files in the directory structure in a canonical way.

It is important that the schema type has great Java support and good C++ support. Python and other languages would be a bonus.

It should allow nested variants of file structures and the specification of a canonical variant at each level.

There may be variants of directory structures but there would always be a canonical layout.

e.g. (using the Java/VFS2 style filename format)

The canonical format:

```
major
        minor
                binaryFileDDMMYY01.bin
                auditFileDDMMYY01.xml
                                /elements
                                        /element[0]...
                binaryFileDDMMYY02.bin
                auditFileDDMMYY02.xml
```

A variant:

```
major
        minor
                12.zip!
                        binaryFileDDMMYY01.bin
                        auditFileDDMMYY01.xml
                                /elements
                                        /element[0]...
                        binaryFileDDMMYY02.bin
                        auditFileDDMMYY02.xml
```

As I am already using XML and XML has the xref/link elements, XML would seem the obvious format. But whatever defacto format I use, I will need to hook into the parser/object model to map the proprietary formats into something that plays with the object model of whatever framework I choose (on Java, perhaps a proprietary SAX/DOM implementation that maps to/from the file format), perhaps using custom URL formats (VFS2 style) or schema extensions to define them, e.g:

```
<xref href="zip:/major/minor/12.zip!auditFileDDMMYY01.xml"/>
```

and

```
<xref href="acme:zip:/major/minor/12.zip!binaryFileDDMMYY01.bin"/>
```

or

```
<xref format="acme" href="zip:/major/minor/12.zip!binaryFileDDMMYY01.bin"/>
```

Is there any alternative to XSD schema that would be better disposed to achieving this end? It need not be XML specific, but must cater for XML interchange.

Comment: Some users here probably know what a `declarative interchange format` is.  I am not one of them.  I am an average Stack Exchange user.  Ipso facto, the average Stack Exchange user does not understand your goals. :) Would you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry. I have tried to clarify my thoughts a bit in the OP. I have some ideas on how I probably could do what I want to do, but I want to find the best fit.